# Make [term] and [terms] tags synonyms

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Are the [term](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/term) and [terms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terms) synonyms already?

If not, maybe they should be made synonyms.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not convinced that [terms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terms) is a great tag, but I've made the merge for the time being. I'll probably retag the questions later today with better tags, so this synonym + merge may have been in vain.

Comment: I proposed the synonyms thing because even if you delete one of those two, someone will use it sooner or later anyway, so I guess the synonyms thing exists for that reason no? In order to change it automatically if someone uses the wrong one.

Comment: Oh, sorry for the confusion. [tag:terms] is the new master tag because it's plural and everything is in place (term will redirect into terms, etc.), but what I meant was that it's not a great tag anyway (e.g. [tag:phrases] can replace it in some cases; in others, it can just be removed).